# float64 no Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Tenho uma tabela `f0219` com uma coluna `Valor`. Originalmente, valor está como `object`. Eu uso o seguinte comando para convertê-lo para `float`.

```
f0219['Valor'] = pd.to_numeric(f0219['Valor'], errors='coerce')
```

Obs: o `astype` não funciona. Acho que é porque essa coluna possui tipos mistos.
Pois bem, após a conversão, quando dou um `f0219.info()`, os tipos das duas colunas da minha tabela aparecem como a seguir:

```
CPF          27417 non-null int64
Valor        0 non-null float64
```

Eu tenho um valor na coluna `Valor` de `4753,20`. Porém, quando tento filtrar todos os valores com o comando abaixo, maiores que `1000`, o resultado me é retornado com uma mensagem de erro:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-68-4f8e4c49b332> in <module>
----> 1 f0219[f0219.Valor>2232,00]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2925             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2926                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2927             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2928             if is_integer(indexer):
   2929                 indexer = [indexer]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2654                                  'backfill or nearest lookups')
   2655             try:
-> 2656                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2657             except KeyError:
   2658                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

TypeError: '(0        False
1        False
2        False
3        False
```

Comment: Por acaso se trocar `,` por `.` resolve? `f0219[f0219.Valor>2232.00]` em vez de `f0219[f0219.Valor>2232,00]`.

Comment: Isso mesmo. Coloquei o '.' na parte decimal e reapliquei a conversão. Funcionou. Grato.